# Add SQL Server Profile

Tags: sql-server

I installed SQL Server 2012 on my PC, but did not have the option to add Sql Profile Tools.  Is there any way to add separate?

Or if someone pass me a link with this tool.

Comment: Do you have SQL Server Management Studio? There should be an installation option for SQL Server Management Tools

Comment: Yes, I have the SQL Management Studio. The option for SQL Profile there should be in: Tools > SQL Profile? But, don't have this option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you installed SQL Server Management Studio? If not install it. If you have your installation media you should be able to add features to your SQL Server including the management tools and the profiler.

Comment: I try install again, but I did not find the option.

Comment: Baffling. Windows will have created a folder in the 'All programs' menus called 'Microsoft SQL Server 2012'. What do you have in there? You should have subfolders called 'Configuration Tools' and 'Performance Tools'. profiler should be in performance tools. Also try looking in the program files folder for your SQL Server installation in \Tools\Binn there should be profiler.exe.

Comment: You're right, he should be there, but is not there. Thank you for help, maybe I try reinstall another time. For while I'll use on the Server.