# ASP.NET - Adding SQL State Server + manipulating it

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4, session

I'm building app for intranet. It is designed so that at one end someone provides data in a custom made form (at run time) or choosing one from template (either provided by me or saved custom-made). At the other end someone can query the data provided. At some point data provided will not be modifiable by the user that provides it.

What I'm doing is basicly trying to store session data:

- that allows user to come back to filling form (as when he had to end it abruptly and then come back to it)
- bring back his custom made form that he designed

What my problem is:

- don't know how to set up the SQL state server correctly
- how to manipulate it (meaning how to change what data is stored, either by storing less data or making custom session data-set that is saved)
- how to manipulate SQL state server

I'm willing to store data in a few tables - for ex. BEFORE(stores forms being filled) and SENT(not modifiable anymore, they will be analized), also FORMDESIGNS(that stores user form templates). I don't know how to wrap my head around it.

What I've read:

- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32545/Exploring-Session-in-ASP-Net
- [Add SQL Server Profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36725920/add-sql-server-profile)
- https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/49677/no-sa-password-no-sql-server-management-studio-no-os-authentication

If you had any step-by-step guide or any other source of information that could help I'd be grateful.

I'm not very experienced in storing session data and databases itself. If you think something might make it easier from what you alr know - don't hold back.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I did find a way to set up SQL correctly + state server in web.config.

What I needed:
1/ SQL Server Managment Studio (SQL SMS)
2/ Go into Security>Logins and set a new user (be sure to check the boxes with aspnet and your local DB/DB set on server)
3/ use the steps and code from http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32545/Exploring-Session-in-ASP-Net 
 + credentials from 2/
4/ You'll have state server working correctly.

When it comes to retrieving session I decided on creating a table that holds user_id and session_id from default aspnet set up (you'll see it in SQL SMS or in SQL Server Explorer in VS). Then when user logs I take his ID and retrieve session. When user ends form the info is deleted from session and form itself saved in database.

As to dynamic forms I'm still stuck on it, but you might use what I alr did.